# Rotate an image in Outlook Client body

Tags: html, css, outlook

I want to rotate an image in the `Outlook` Client in the body as I am getting a rotated image from the cloud. Can someone help me with this.I have tried the following

`string htmlBody = "<html><body> Dear user,<br/><br/> "  + @"<img src='" + filePath + "' width='200' height='200' style='transform: rotate(90deg)' /> <br/><br/> Regards,<br/> Management<br/></body></html>"`;

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes after img src might give you an issue.
Rather use the double quotes for img src

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Outlook Client doesn’t support transform.

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/transforms/transform/)